# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '07/06/2019'

Tags: pandas, string, linear-regression

I am performing a linear regression analysis on bike share data. I am interested in predicting the bikecount based on the other factors.

So I split the data like so :

x = df[['rain', 'temp', 'rhum', 'msl', 'wdsp', 'day', 'month', 'monthname', 'season']]

y = df['bikecount']

Then, when I get to this stage: lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

it returns this error: **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '07/06/2019'**

I tried converting this column to float using df['date'] = float(df['date']) but that returns the error **TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>**

I don't understand why this keeps coming up. I'm not even interested in the date column for my analysis. Any help would be appreciated!

0   datetime   6040 non-null   datetime64[ns]
1   bikecount  6040 non-null   int64
2   rain       6040 non-null   float64
3   temp       6040 non-null   float64
4   rhum       6040 non-null   int64
5   msl        6040 non-null   float64
6   wdsp       6040 non-null   int64
**7   date       6040 non-null   object**
8   time       6040 non-null   object
9   day        6040 non-null   object
10  month      6040 non-null   int64
11  monthname  6040 non-null   object
12  season     6040 non-null   object
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(3), int64(4), object(5)
memory usage: 613.6+ KB

| datetime | bikecount | rain | temp | rhum | msl | wdsp | date | datetime.1 | day | month | monthname | season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0.0 | 9.9 | 78 | 1036.0 | 4 | 01/01/2019 | 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 1 | January | Winter |
| 2019-01-01 07:00:00 | 1 | 0.0 | 8.3 | 87 | 1036.8 | 2 | 01/01/2019 | 07:00:00 | Tuesday | 1 | January | Winter |
| 2019-01-01 11:00:00 | 2 | 0.0 | 9.5 | 89 | 1038.8 | 3 | 01/01/2019 | 11:00:00 | Tuesday | 1 | January | Winter |
| 2019-01-01 12:00:00 | 4 | 0.0 | 10.1 | 84 | 1038.7 | 3 | 01/01/2019 | 12:00:00 | Tuesday | 1 | January | Winter |

Comment: For this date `01/01/2019`, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date to the elapsed seconds since 1970-01-01

```
# Sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/11/2019']}

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True) \
               .sub(pd.to_datetime(0)) \
               .dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
# Before conversion:
>>> df
         date
0  01/11/2019

# After conversion:
>>> df
           date
0  1.572566e+09
```